# How to refactor this repetitive jquery ajax pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, refactoring

I received this complicated jquery based ajax structure.

```
$.ajax({
  url: ("example/example.php"),
  type: "post",
  data: {
    data1 = datafromphp_1;
    data2 = datafromphp_2;
  }
  dataType: "json",
},
success: function (datafromphp_2){
  return function(datafromphp_2){
    $.ajax({
         // Same structure as outer structure
      success: function (){
           $.ajax({
               // same structure as outer structure. The structure is recursively repeating.  
             success: function(){
               // The structure is recursively repeating..
               // Some complicated embedded html strings with jquery.
               // Each ajax makes cells dynamically. Further inner ajax codes make smaller cells in each cells made by outer ajax codes.

             }
           }); 
      }
    });
  };
  }(datafromphp_2)
});
```

What customers should see on browsers like this.
  [image]

And each cells have to be generated by dynamically. If there is no data on server, browser have to show nothing. To generate cells dynamically, jquery codes are implemented like this.

```
$("<label>").text("this is label example),$(input type = 'text' name='cell0' style = blablabla...), ("other html codes to decorate cell"), ... , ...
```

So even CSS, php, html and javascript(.js) files are divided, javascript files are too big and It seems like other html codes! Extremely, one js file for implementing this view has 20 times of tabs and nested block structure.

Is there any way to simplify these structure? I can't find the proper solutions to refactor this.

Comment: http://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/06/why-i-prefer-ajax-promise.html

Comment: You are looking for recursion.